# Why does it seem like Piston's position (0, 0) is halfway down the window on the left?

Tags: rust, coordinates, rust-piston

I'm hitting what I assume is a pretty basic misunderstanding of how to draw things using the Rust Piston library. Here is the main function I'm working with, mostly copied from beginner tutorials.

```
extern crate piston_window;

use piston_window::*;

fn main() {
    let dims = (640.0, 480.0);
    let mut window: PistonWindow =
        WindowSettings::new("Hello, Piston!", (dims.0 as u32, dims.1 as u32))
            .exit_on_esc(true)
            .build()
            .unwrap();
    while let Some(e) = window.next() {
        match e {
            Event::Loop(Loop::Render(_)) => {
                window.draw_2d(&e, |c, g| {
                    clear([1.0; 4], g);
                    rectangle(
                        [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                        [0.0, 0.0, dims.0, dims.1],
                        c.transform,
                        g,
                    );
                });
            }
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to draw a red rectangle the size of the window, but when I run this function, I get a red box drawn on the lower-left corner of the frame, not occupying the whole window as I might expect.

[image: red rectangle appears to the lower left corner of the frame]

Oddly enough, if I change the dimensions to `(480.0, 480.0)` so that the window is a square, the box fills up the window like I would expect. I imagine this is simply me misunderstanding how Piston treats coordinates. What exactly am I missing here, and why does it seem like the position (0, 0) is halfway down the window on the left?

Comment: I copied and ran your exact code - the red box is anchored to the top left of the window...

Comment: Well that's alarming. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 running Rust 1.29.2 and `piston_window` 0.81.0, if that tells you anything.

Comment: I'm using piston_window 0.82 on Mac OS 10.13.6

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xGpM.png

Comment: Tried on Windows 10 and works as expected.

Comment: Seems like you may need to log a bug with piston. It will probably be a bug in one of their dependencies.

Comment: I encountered the same problem (on Arch Linux). Downgrading to piston_window 0.64.0 solved it for me. Did you file a bug report or anything?

Comment: @EliasRiedelGårding That's a relief to know that it's not just me then. With that in mind, I have now filed [an issue on their repo](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston_window/issues/238).